# Exponentiation of Diagonalizable Matrix

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, diagonalization

Wikipedia says that

"If $A = UDU^{−1}$ and D is diagonal, then $e^{A} = Ue^{D}U^{−1}$"

Why is this the case?

I understand that $e^D$ yields a matrix where $M_{i,j} = e^{D_{i,j}}$, but how is it possible that we are able to factor $U$ and $U^{-1}$ out? I can not seem to find the logic anywhere.

Comment: How are you defining the exponential of a matrix?  Basically, whichever definition you use should be invariant under similarity, i.e. $\exp(U M U^{-1}) = U \exp(M) U^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^A=I+A+\frac{1}{2}A^2+\cdots$$
$$=UU^{-1}+UDU^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}UDU^{-1}UDU^{-1}+\cdots$$
$$=UU^{-1}+UDU^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}UD^2U^{-1}+\cdots$$
$$=U\bigg(I+D+\frac{1}{2}D^2+\cdots\bigg)U^{-1}$$
$$Ue^DU^{-1}$$

Comment: Taylor Expansion?

Comment: Yes. That's the definition of $e^A$.

Answer (score 1):

It is know that $t \mapsto e^{tA}$ is the only solution of the differential equation $$X' =AX, \quad X(0) =1.$$ If you prove that $Ue^{tD}U^{-1}$ is a solution of $X'=UDU^{-1}X$, then by uniqueness you will have $$e^{tUDU^{-1}}=Ue^{tD}U^{-1}$$ and you will get the conclusion by evalutating at $t=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $e^A$ does not refer to the matrix such that $(e_A)_{i,j} = e^{A_{i,j}}$, just as the expression $A^2$ doesn't mean the matrix with $i,j$-entry equal to $(A_{i,j})^2$.

What is meant by $e^A$ is the matrix
$$
e^A = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{A^n}{n!}.
$$

This is the limit of the matrices $B_n := \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{A^i}{i!}$. You do know that each $U D^i U^{-1} = (U D U^{-1})^i = A^i$, and you know that the diagonal entry $D^i_{j,j} = (D_{j,j})^i$. So
$$
U^{-1} (B_n)_{j,j} U = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{(D_{j,j})^i}{i!},
$$
and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} U^{-1} (B_n)_{j,j} U = e^{D_{j,j}}$. That is, $\lim_{n \to \infty} U^{-1} B_n U = e^{D}$, and since multiplication of matrices is continuous, we obtain
$$
U^{-1} (\lim_{n \to \infty} B_n) U = e^{D}
$$
 Multiplying on the left by $U$ and on the right by $U^{-1}$, we get
$$
e^A = U e^D U^{-1}.
$$